# How to create a slide of background images using Pure Javascript or a pure Javascript library

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'd like to make the below in a way that I can have two images slide in the background but have I'm stuck on how to implement a slide of background images. Kindly assist, any assistance will be highly appreciated.

```css
#header-image {
  background-image: url('/images/photography1.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-image">
  <div class="overlay" data-aos="fade-down-right">
    <h1>Photography Logo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made an example for you using javascript, as well as modified your html and css. Was such a result necessary? If you have any questions, please let me know.

```js
let anime = document.querySelector('#header-image');
var step = 0;

function animate() {
  if (step > -200) {
      anime.style.transform = 'translateX('+ step +'vw)';
    } else {
      anime.style.transform = 'transformX(100vw)';
      step = 100;
  }
}

setInterval(function () {
   step = step - 100;
   animate();
}, 5000);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header-image {  
  border: none;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 1s;
  display: flex;
}

#photo_section_one {
  background-image: url('https://img.desktopwallpapers.ru/newyear/pics/wide/1920x1200/5f7ff83acdb7b743fb61468954e9c511.jpg');
  width: 100vw;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#photo_section_two {
  background-image: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/N_97o7XR3tJd8Thp4vFQxXqqQVMSgBNhjGlvvHa9bDnpW-i4v6J9EElWWMSC8qumCbDAfvAjroBDWBu8F1HPl-hZX1BsYOk-wDNO26pT19W90o8n22aABvQ');
  width: 100vw;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-image">
   <div id="photo_section_one">
    <div class="overlay" data-aos="fade-down-right">
      <h1>Photography Logo</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="photo_section_two">
    <div class="overlay" data-aos="fade-down-right">
      <h1>Photography Logo</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second solution using an array of images. The images change as on the site you showed.

```js
let anime = document.querySelector('#header-image');
let images = ['https://vjoy.cc/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/1-39.jpg', 'https://img.desktopwallpapers.ru/newyear/pics/wide/1920x1200/5f7ff83acdb7b743fb61468954e9c511.jpg'];

let index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
  anime.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[index] + ')';
    index++;
      if (index >= images.length) {
        index = 0;
      }
}, 5000);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header-image {  
  border: none;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: 1s;
  background-image: url('https://img.desktopwallpapers.ru/newyear/pics/wide/1920x1200/5f7ff83acdb7b743fb61468954e9c511.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="header-image">
   <div id="photo_section_one">
    <div class="overlay" data-aos="fade-down-right">
      <h1>Photography Logo</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was such a code necessary? What are you referring to in that question?

Comment: @AlphyGacheru, I meant whether such a result is needed, but not the code.

Comment: I'm not sure maybe you can advice in regard to your experience. I'm getting started with projects and wanted something of the sort as in this website http://duruthemes.com/demo/html/annie/dark/index.html 

The background image to have two that are sliding!

Comment: @AlphyGacheru, My solution is like one of many solution options. You had to indicate the link to this site in your question so that the programmer had an idea of the result you need.

Comment: Got it, would you have take the same approach if it was you? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve the same!

Comment: This example didn't have the same slide direction and the text moves with the images, and I though I could improve it, so I made the whole thing from scratch and edited my post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613100/how-to-create-a-slide-of-background-images-using-pure-javascript-or-a-pure-javas/65613682#65613682

Comment: Second solution is PERFECT... Thank you very much. You've helped me BIG.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot do exactly what you are asking for. But, you can create something similar though z-index and absolute positioning, some css, and some js. You would have to create a div behind the text and animate it using css, while using some js to make it continuously loop.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("slide-pos-1")[0] != undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("background-slide")[0].classList.add("slide-pos-2")
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("background-slide")[0].classList.remove("slide-pos-1")
      document.getElementsByClassName("background-slide")[0].classList.remove("slide-pos-2")
    }, 1500)
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("background-slide")[0].classList.add("slide-pos-1")
  }
}, 6000)
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background-slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  transform:translate(0,0);
  transition: transform 0s ease-out;
}

.slide-pos-1{
transform:translate(calc(-100% / 3),0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

.slide-pos-2{
transform:translate(calc(-200% / 3),0);
  transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

.header-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
flex:1;
}

img {
object-fit: cover;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-image">
  <div class="background-slide slide-pos-1">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" /></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Photography Logo</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, this one doesn't slide the text along with the image, and the slide direction is the same. Credit of s.kuznetsov for making me realize that and revise my answer.